# Hooks is not working on server in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a hook for query log.
Step 1 : `$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;` in config.php

Step 2 :

```
 $hook['post_controller'] = array(
    'class' => 'Db_log',
    'function' => 'logQueries', 
    'filename' => 'db_log.php', 
    'filepath' => 'hooks' 
);
// hooks.php
```

Step 3 : Hooks folder created the file called Db_log.php

Step 4 : Code in // Name of Class as mentioned in `$hook['post_controller]`

```
class Db_log {

    function __construct() {
        // Anything except exit()
    }

    // Name of function same as mentioned in Hooks Config
    function logQueries() {
        $CI = &get_instance();
        $filepath = APPPATH . 'logs/Query-log-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.php';
        $handle = fopen($filepath, "a+");
        $times = $CI->db->query_times;
        foreach ($CI->db->queries as $key => $query) {
            date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
            $sql = $query . " \n Execution Time:" . $times[$key];
            fwrite($handle, $sql . "\n\n");
        }
        $line .= "-----------------------------------------------\n";
        fwrite($handle, $line . "\n");
        fclose($handle);      // Close the file
    }
}
```

My Question is When ever controller is call then hook is running properly in local
On server hook is not working, Set the permission 755,777,644 but still not working.

Comment: Which CI version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Please change array in hooks.php as bellow

```
$hook['post_controller'] = array(
    'class' => 'Db_log',
    'function' => 'logQueries', 
    'filename' => 'Db_log.php', 
    'filepath' => 'hooks' 
);
```

You have written wrong file name